# How can we find maximum spanning tree in complete graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, graph-theory, number-theory

Given an array of `n` positive integers, how can we find maximum spanning tree in complete graph, considering weight of edge `(i, j) = gcd(a[i], a[j])`?

I know one solution with complexity `O(n^2)`, but `n<=10^5`, so I need something faster.

UPD:

As mentioned in comments:

> The question here is getting an algorithm that exploits the special
>   structure of the graph.

Comment: @thebenman It's not a duplicate, since the O(n^2) algorithm known to the asker is presumably dense Prim. The question here is getting an algorithm that exploits the special structure of the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the other constraints, you could use a variant of Kruskal's algorithm. For each input number, factor it and associate it with its divisors, e.g., given

```
[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  8,  9, 10, 12]
```

we build a map

```
{ 1: [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  8,  9, 10, 12],
  2: [ 2,  4,  8, 10, 12],
  3: [ 3,  9, 12],
  4: [ 4,  8, 12],
  5: [ 5, 10],
  6: [12],
  8: [ 8],
  9: [ 9],
 10: [10],
 12: [12]}.
```

Iterate over this map in key-descending order. For each list, unite those disjoint sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

- First build the graph.
- Store the egdes with minimum weight on a minHeap
- Remove the minimum edges from the graph one by one (taking care not to disconnect the graph)
- At each step, check if the graph is a tree

the last step is quite tricky. You won't need to run all the graph always, once you know a tree has (n-1) edges.